# msdeploy failure, ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: visual-studio, iis, webdeploy

I'm publishing a web site to Azure from visual studio 2022. It returns ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED error.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4455,5): Error ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED: Web deployment task failed.   (Connected to the remote computer ("substratebot.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.    Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)

I'm sure the user account and password used for deployment is right. (I get it from the web profile, and I used them to publish successfully 1 month ago.)

pubxml file:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <ResourceId>/subscriptions/de5f106e-7904-4cac-b6e7-4bcab624340a/resourcegroups/SubstrateBot/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/SubstrateBot</ResourceId>
    <ResourceGroup>SubstrateBot</ResourceGroup>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://substratebot.azurewebsites.net</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>substratebot.scm.azurewebsites.net:443</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>SubstrateBot</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>$SubstrateBot</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <_DestinationType>AzureWebSite</_DestinationType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

How can I check if the credential has the IIS management permission to the web site even though no way to login the remote computer?

I checked that the Basic Authentication is disabled in site's configuration. However it is using Basic authtype in msdeploy. Could this block the credential authorization?

[image: site's configuration page]

Any method for debugging is pretty appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by enabling Basic Authentication setting for the web site. You could running below Azure CLI to enable it.

*az resource update --resource-group  --name scm --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies --parent sites/ --set properties.allow=true*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYMsm.png)

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.